# Does it matter if I use a 110v fuser or a 220v fuser

Tags: printing

I have a printer that can take a 110v fuser or a 220v fuser.

- What is the difference?
- Can using the wrong one cause issues?
- What other things should I consider when choosing a certain voltage on a printer fuser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some countries use 110V power.  Some countries use 220V power.  You should use whichever is correct for the power mains in the location where you are.  I am surprised to hear that this isn't a unit that supports both specs, but I'm not super familiar with printers so maybe that would be difficult to do.  Most computing equipment these days supports both standards with a manual toggle, though.

(These numbers are old specs and the actual power these days I believe is 120V/230V but essentially it comes down to this.  More to the point, you can probably only easily find the correct one in your location.)

Comment: EU is 230 V ± 6%. South Dakota (Paul's location) is 110 V.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - Doh, didn't occur to me to check his user profile. :)  Yeah, in the US you'll want the 110V unit.